# Combining outputs of dual channel equalizer

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, filter, spice

I'm building a two channel equalizer, essentially a bandpass filter and I've run into a small problem. I've successfully gotten my low and high pass filters to work but I can't get them to "add up" properly. At first, I was having issues with the outputs being 180 out of phase so I added an inverting amp to correct that but now I'm unsure of how to combine the two outputs.

[image: Spice simulation]

The green line is how I want the end result to output(ish)

My code: https://pastebin.com/55hEQRxc

Comment: You don't use your virtual ground anywhere? What's the issue when you cascade the LPF after the HPF?

Comment: @sstobbe the virtual ground is needed in the physical design due to the microcontroller I'm using to readout. Cascading them works fine but I want to be able to individually control the effect of each filter with a pot. If I put them in series, putting a pot in front of one affects both.

Comment: Your green line shows a 1 st order bandpass filter, if that's what you want using a first order LPF and HPF tuneable by a pot is much easier than adjusting a second order filter.

Comment: Looks like you operate them in parallel. You have to put them in series!

Comment: Have you looked into the inverting summator (opamp circuit)?